# Issue with converting spark-sql which has a oracle blob column into java byte[]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would appreciate if anybody can point me to the code snippet for
converting spark SQL that has a  oracle blob column into java byte[], here is what I have, but getting error.

```
Dataset<tableX> dataset = sparkSession.read()
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xx )(PORT = 1234))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xy)))")
    .option("dbtable", "(select lob_id , blob_data from tableX ) test1")
    .option("user", "user1")
    .option("password", "pass1")
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    .load();
//dataset.show();
dataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<tableX>) row -> {
  byte blobData[] = row.getAs("blob_data");

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[DataframeReader.load](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#load--) returns an *untyped* dataframe (aka `Dataset<Row>`). When calling `foreach` with a `ForeachFunction<tableX>` a compiler error will occur.

**Option 1**: stick to the untyped dataframe and use `ForeachFunction<Row>`:

```java
Dataset<Row> dataframe = sparkSession.read() ... .load();

dataframe.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
    byte blobData[] = (byte[])row.getAs("blob_data");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blobData));
});
```

**Option 2**: after reading the dataframe transform it into a *typed* dataset and use `ForeachFunction<tableX>`. A class `tableX` should exist and contain the fields of the original query as members:

```java
Dataset<tableX> dataset = dataframe.as(Encoders.bean(tableX.class));
dataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<tableX>) row -> {
    byte blobData[] = row.getBlob_data();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blobData));
});
```

Option 2 assumes that the class `tableX` has a getter for the field `blob_data` named `getBlob_data()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both the options, I am able to proceed bit further, but when trying tow write the blobData to a File, getting exception:

Comment: Maybe a new exception is worth a new question?